# How to know which plug-in/workflow/entity updates data

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

In my plugin I have a code to check the execution context Depth to avoid infinite loop once the plugin updates itself/entity, but there are cases that entity is being updated from other plugin or workflow with depth 2,3 or 4 and for that specific calls, from that specific plugin I want to process the call and not stop even if the Depth is bigger then 1.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a different approach might be better? I've never needed to consider `Depth` in my plug-ins. I've heard of other people doing the same as you (checking the depth to avoid code from running twice or more) but I usually avoid this by making any changes to the underlying entity in the Pre Operation stage.

If, for example, I have code that changes the name of an Opportunity whenever the opportunity is updated, by putting my code in the post-operation stage of the Update my code would react to the user changing a value by sending a separate `Update` request back to the platform to apply the change. This new `Update` itself causes my plug-in to fire again - infinite loop.

If I put my logic in the Pre-Operation stage, I do it differently: the user's change fires the plugin. Before the user's change is committed to the platform, my code is invoked. This time I can look at the `Target` that was sent in the `InputParameters` to the `Update` message. If the `name` attribute does not exist in the `Target` (i.e. it wasn't updated) then I can append an attribute called `name` with the desired value to the `Target` and this value will get carried through to the platform. In other words, I am injecting my value into the record before it is committed, thereby avoiding the need to issue another `Update` request. Consequently, my changes causes no further plug-ins to fire.

Obviously I presume that your scenario is more complex but I'd be very surprised if it couldn't fit the same pattern.

Comment: Please remember to mark this as answer if it resolves your issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by agreeing with everything that Greg said above - if possible refactor the design to avoid this situation.

If that is not possible you will need to use the [IPluginExecutionContext.SharedVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328579.aspx) to communicate between the plug-ins.

Check for a SharedVariable at the start of your plug-in and then set/update it as appropriate. The specific design you'll use will vary based on the complexity you need to manage. I always get use a string with the message and entity ID - easy enough to serialize and deserialize. Then I always know whether I'm already executing the against a certain message for a specific record or not.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause synchronization issues ? I can have concurrent calls.

Comment: What do you mean by "concurrent calls"? The pipeline in synchronous for each entity-message combination.